# Aligning Symbols with Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been attempting to create a swirly, hypnotic animation in flash with random words fading in and then scaling out. Initially I set things up with motion tweens made randomly visible by a timer, but the timer inevitably fell out of sync with the animation leading to the word switching in mid-animation.

After some research, using ENTER_FRAME Event to trigger animation coded in Actionscript seemed like the solution for synchronizing things properly. However, while modifying the visibility and the initial fade in have been trivially easy to code, scaling while maintaining proper alignment on the stage has proven incredibly difficult.

From what I can tell, I should be using stage.stageWidth(and Height)/2 - the width/height of instance /2 to set the appropriate x/y coordinates to realign the instance in the center of the stage after it's been re-sized by adjusting the scaleX/Y of the instance, but everything is slightly out of alignment.

Each instance I'm using started as a Text object in Flash Professional CS5.5 and has been converted into a Movie Clip object with the instance names listed in the code below.

The initial function that chooses the word and modifies it

```
function runMany(event:Event):void {
if (cnt == 0) {
    randomWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    scaling(randomWord, scale);
    setAlpha(randomWord, alphaLevel);
    visibility(randomWord, true);
    cnt++;
} else if (cnt <= 50) {
    alphaLevel = alphaLevel + .02;
    setAlpha(randomWord, alphaLevel);
    cnt++;

} else if (cnt < 97) {
    alphaLevel = alphaLevel - .02;
    scale = scale - .02;
    scaling(randomWord, scale);
    setAlpha(randomWord, alphaLevel);
    if (scale > 0) {
        cnt++;
    } else {
        cnt = 97;
    }
} else if (cnt == 97) {
    cnt = 0;
    alphaLevel = 0;
    scale = .8;
    visibility(randomWord, false);
    scaling(randomWord, scale);
    setAlpha(randomWord, alphaLevel);
}
}
```

The function that, should, be scaling and aligning the word

```
function scaling(ref, setting):void {
    if (ref == 0) {
        if (setting == 1) {
            watch.width = 515.50;
            watch.height = 209;
        } else {
            watch.scaleX = setting;
            watch.scaleY = setting;
        }
    watch.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - watch.width/2;
    watch.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - watch.height/2;
}
if (ref == 1) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        slave.width = 552.55;
        slave.height = 266.75;
    }else {
        slave.scaleX = setting;
        slave.scaleY = setting;
    }
    slave.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - slave.width/2;
    slave.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - slave.height/2;
}
if (ref == 2) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        letGo.width = 574.45;
        letGo.height = 271;
    } else {
        letGo.scaleX = setting;
        letGo.scaleY = setting;
    }
    letGo.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - letGo.width/2;
    letGo.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - letGo.height/2;
}
if (ref == 3) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        obey.width = 536.95;
        obey.height = 339.15;
    } else {
        obey.scaleX = setting;
        obey.scaleY = setting;
    }
    obey.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - obey.width/2;
    obey.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - obey.height/2;
}
if (ref == 4) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        dontThink.width = 629.60;
        dontThink.height = 184.90
    } else {
        dontThink.scaleX = setting;
        dontThink.scaleY = setting;
    }
    dontThink.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - dontThink.width/2;
    dontThink.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - dontThink.height/2;
}
if (ref == 5) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        blank.width = 601.30;
        blank.height = 195.85;
    } else {
        blank.scaleX = setting;
        blank.scaleY = setting;
    }
    blank.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - blank.width/2;
    blank.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - blank.height/2;
}
if (ref == 6) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        mindless.width = 800.20;
        mindless.height = 187.25;
    } else {
        mindless.scaleX = setting;
        mindless.scaleY = setting;
    }
    mindless.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - mindless.width/2;
    mindless.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - mindless.height/2;
}
if (ref == 7) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        property1.width = 632.60;
        property1.height = 326.85;
    } else {
        property1.scaleX = setting;
        property1.scaleY = setting;
    }
    property1.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - property1.width/2;
    property1.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - property1.height/2;
}
if (ref == 8) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        owned.width = 670.65;
        owned.height = 209.75;
    } else {
        owned.scaleX = setting;
        owned.scaleY = setting;
    }
    owned.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - owned.width/2;
    owned.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - owned.height/2;
}
if (ref == 9) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        dontResist.width = 791.05;
        dontResist.height = 142.45;
    } else {
        dontResist.scaleX = setting;
        dontResist.scaleY = setting;
    }
    dontResist.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - dontResist.width/2;
    dontResist.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - dontResist.height/2;
}
if (ref == 10) {
    if (setting == 1) {
        submit.width = 793.40;
        submit.height = 244.35;
    } else {
        submit.scaleX = setting;
        submit.scaleY = setting;
    }
    submit.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - submit.width/2;
    submit.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - submit.height/2;
}
}
```

Comment: how are they out of sync - and you might want to look into something like Greensock's tween classes.  They will allow you do everything you need including sync.  http://www.greensock.com

Comment: @Gone3d When I was using a timer it would get through part of the animation for one word and then skip to a different one. I have considered greensock, but I didn't see anything that would apply an alignment, just animate it

Comment: @user1942867 You don't seem to call scaling when cnt <= 50. Not sure if that's by design or part of the problem.

Comment: @Pixel Elephant it's by design. Before cnt hits 50 it's calling setAlpha to increase the alpha of the instance to create the fade in effect.

Comment: You're likely having issues because the scaling occurs from the registration point, which is generally in the top left corner, so things get pushed down and to the right as they get scaled up, likely you're looking to scale objects from their center point instead.  If you check out rotation about a point in AS3 I believe the same concept will apply to scaling, so you can slide each movie clip up and to the left using the translation on it's matrix, then do the scaling after the transformation is done.  This has never been an easy task for me either but eventually it works out.

Comment: You've converted Text into a MovieClip, which I assume means the Text is a layer inside said clip. Why don't you just position this clip in the centre, and inside it, position the text centrally? Scaling the clip (instead of the text) will keep it central at all time - I'm worried I may have misunderstood as this seems a bit too simple(!)...